# Linked Query in MS Access 2007 to SQL database - ODBC error - How do I see the linking details?

Tags: microsoft-access, sql, query, odbc

I am converting an old Access 2003 database to 2007.  It has a query linking to a SQL database.  How do I look at the link, e.g., whether it using a DSN, etc.?

The query has the globe to the left of it indicating it is linked.  When I try to Open it, it says "ODBC - connection to '(a database name)' failed."

I have searched and seen many posts on Access tables linking to another database, but none of a query linking to another database.

Comment: Check out Control Panel -> Setup data sources

Answer (score 1):

You can find the connect string of a table by typing this in the Immediate Windows in the VBE:

```
  ?CurrentDB.TableDefs("TableToCheck").Connect
```

That should get you started...

Comment: I need to see the connect information for a Query, not a Table.

Comment: Thanks.  I just change TableDefs to QueryDefs and got the connection information I need.